# getting a custom tag value using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="selTest">
    <option custom="123" value="abc">111</option>
    <option custom="456" value="def">222</option>
<select>
```

...using jQuery, **how do I get option.custom where option.value=selTest.val()**

in other words: if selTest.val = def, then $x=456 (I'm trying to get the value of custom into $x)

Comment: I'd drop the non-validating custom attribute in favor of something like `.data()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedCustomValue = $("select#selTest option:selected").attr("custom");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectElement = $("#selTest")[0];
alert(selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].getAttribute("custom"));
```

Comment: Why not go all the way and use `document.getElementById('selText')` instead of `$('#selTest')[0]` when you're not using jQuery on the second line? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('#selTest').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var custom = $('option[value="' + value +'"]').attr('custom');
  ...
});
```