# how to get last value in srcset property in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

my code is :

```
<figure class="im-entry-thumb clearfix">
    <img width="770" height="480" src="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg" class="attachment-post size-post wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg 770w, http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-280x175.jpg 280w" sizes="(max-width: 770px) 100vw, 770px">  </figure>
```

I want to get my last value srcset. Means:

```
http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-280x175.jpg
```

please help.tanks

Comment: $('img').attr('srcset').split(',').pop();

Comment: @JYoThI  This all amounts to be received, which I do not want srcset

Comment: no it will return last one only

Comment: try my below answer @Mohammad najjary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get like this use `split()` and `pop()`

```js
//alert($('img').attr('srcset').split(',').pop());

console.log($('img').attr('srcset').split(',').pop());

console.log($('img').attr('srcset').split(',').pop().trim().split(' ')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="im-entry-thumb clearfix">
    <img width="770" height="480" src="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg" class="attachment-post size-post wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg 770w, http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-280x175.jpg 280w" sizes="(max-width: 770px) 100vw, 770px">  </figure>
```

Comment: can you update your question with current code @Mohammadnajjary

Answer (score 0):

You can using like:

$('img').attr('srcset').split(' ').slice(-2)[0]

Answer (score 0):

It's like a custom tag right ? I found out a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248128/getting-a-custom-tag-value-using-jquery). So take a look bellow then you can do something just do like:

```js
console.log("showing result: " + $("img").attr("srcset"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="im-entry-thumb clearfix">
    <img width="770" height="480" src="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg" class="attachment-post size-post wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-770x480.jpg 770w, http://sample.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled-1-280x175.jpg 280w" sizes="(max-width: 770px) 100vw, 770px">  
</figure>
```